# Android: What to use for rendering the layers of photo-editor?

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas, android-canvas, android-view

**Hello friends!**
I need to create a photo editor, which allow to put the emoticons, text and drawing with a brush on the picture.

[Open the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AprA0.png)

An editor must be able to change the position of smiles & text, their size and rotation with two fingers (multi-touch).

Mechanics is clear to me. I found ready realization of multi-controller:
https://github.com/lukehutch/android-multitouch-controller

But I don't understand how better visualize all the layers in terms of performance:

```
Layer 3 - text
Layer 2 - emoticons
Layer 1 - drawing
Layer 0 - photo
```

I am afraid to use the canvas, without your opinion. I heard that the canvas buggy when displaying a large number of images.

I found examples visualize the layers of images using layer-list with the  's inside. I think this method will be more performance numbers for my task.
But I have not found documentation of how to update the position (top / left) when you move an item.

**My question is:** What is the best use for the visualization of all layers and the possibility to save the final image (merge all layers)?

Please help, what to choose and what is the right path!
Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas` is not buggy. It's the only way for you to render things onto a `Bitmap`. By the looks of your requirement, I think you need to draw your `Layers` onto different bitmaps. `Layer 0` will be your default bitmap. Every other layer will be individual bitmaps on their own. The reason they have to be on a bitmap of their own is so that you can move them as you wish.

You final merge will be to draw all these bitmaps, on the default bitmap via `Canvas.drawBitmap()` call.